# Flutter "background service running" notification always showing in notification bar. How to remove it?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I am using the [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package in the app to get the notification from firebase when the app is in the terminated state but this background service notification creates a bad experience for users. Is there any way to hide it so I can still able to run this service in the background?  [Background service image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdxo3.jpg)

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_background_service/flutter_background_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:zooper_ai/app/componets/messenger.dart';
import 'package:zooper_ai/app/core/color.dart';
import 'package:zooper_ai/app/helper/sqflite_db/database_functions.dart';
import 'package:zooper_ai/app/modules/drawer_menu/adhoc_bookings/view/adhoc_booking.dart';
import 'package:zooper_ai/app/modules/bottomsheet/botttom_sheet_screen/view/bottom_sheet.dart';
import 'package:zooper_ai/app/modules/splash/view/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:zooper_ai/app/providers/providers.dart';
import 'package:zooper_ai/app/routes/routes.dart';
import 'package:zooper_ai/app/services/notification/notification_services.dart';

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  NotificationServices()
      .sendNotification("TestApp", "${message.data['notificationTitle']}");
}

void initialiseNotification() async {
  InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: NotificationServices().androidInitializationSettings,
  );

  await NotificationServices().flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: notificationResponse
      // onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: notificationResponse,
      // onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationResponse,
      );
}

Future<dynamic> notificationResponse(args) async {
  if (NotificationServices().notifyredirect != null) {
    log("if some notifications come");
    log(NotificationServices().notifyredirect.toString());
    if (NotificationServices().notifyredirect ==
        "notificationCustomerConfigUpdate") {
      Routes.push(
          screen: CurvedBottomNavBar(
        page: 1,
      ));
    } else if (NotificationServices().notifyredirect ==
        "notificationOnGeofenceTrigger") {
      NotificationServices().findNotifiedRide();
    }

    //log("| asss ride id   ass $NotificationServices().notifyredirect");
  }
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await ScreenUtil.ensureScreenSize();
  FlutterBackgroundService();
  //if (await checkInternetConnectivity()) {
  log("here from here");
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
    if (message != null) {
      // RemoteNotification? notification = message!.notification;
      AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
          AndroidNotificationDetails(NotificationServices().channel.id,
              NotificationServices().channel.name,
              importance: Importance.high,
              priority: Priority.high,
              playSound: true);

      NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
          NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);

      //AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      var channelId = 0;
      print(
          "  notification details : ${NotificationServices().flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin}");
      // if (message.data['notificationType'] == 'notificationOnGeofenceTrigger') {
      //   channelId = 2;

      NotificationServices().notifyredirect = message.data['notificationType'];
      NotificationServices().rideIdNotification = message.data['rideId'];
      NotificationServices().flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(channelId,
          "Zooper", "${message.data['notificationTitle']}", notificationDetails,
          payload: 'mesaf');

      FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
          alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
    } else {
      log("data is null");
    }
  });
  // final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  //     FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  //     flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(notificationId);

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(NotificationServices().channel.id,
            NotificationServices().channel.name,
            importance: Importance.high,
            priority: Priority.high,
            playSound: true);

    NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);

    //AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
    var channelId = 0;
    print(
        "  notification details : ${NotificationServices().flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin}");
    // if (message.data['notificationType'] == 'notificationOnGeofenceTrigger') {
    //   channelId = 2;

    NotificationServices().notifyredirect = message.data['notificationType'];
    NotificationServices().rideIdNotification = message.data['rideId'];
    NotificationServices().flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(channelId,
        "Zooper", "${message.data['notificationTitle']}", notificationDetails,
        payload: 'mesaf');

    FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
        alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    if (message != null) {
      NotificationServices()
          .sendNotification("Zooper", "${message.data['notificationTitle']}");
    } else {
      log("backround from");
    }
    // print("A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published");
    // print("Messagenotfi ${message.data['notificationTitle']}");
  });

  initialiseNotification();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);

  await initiolizeDatabase();
  await getcityList();
  await gettimeSloteSqflite();
  await getRosterSqflite();
  await getCompanyInfoSqflit();
  runApp(Provders.provders());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // initState() {

  // super.initState();
  // }

  void showNotification() {
    NotificationServices().flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0,
        "Testing",
        "Hiw you doing",
        NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                NotificationServices().channel.id,
                NotificationServices().channel.name,
                channelDescription: NotificationServices().channel.description,
                importance: Importance.high,
                color: Colors.blue,
                playSound: true,
                icon: 'assets/ui/images/Empty.png')));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
        splitScreenMode: false,
        minTextAdapt: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
          return MaterialApp(
              initialRoute: '/',
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
                return MediaQuery(
                  data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
                    textScaleFactor: 0.85,
                  ),
                  child: child!,
                );
              },
              routes: {
                'bottomSheet': (context) => CurvedBottomNavBar(),
                '/adhoc': (context) => const MyAdhoc(),
              },
              navigatorKey: Routes.navigatorKey,
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              title: 'Test',
            scaffoldMessengerKey:Messenger.rootScaffoldMessengerKey,
              //darkTheme: darkThemeData(context),
              theme: lightThemeData(context),
              home: const SplashScreen());
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the notification, just add
`isForegroundMode:false`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).